# How to expand haskell expressions?

Tags: haskell

How to expand

```
concat( map (interleave 2) [[3,4][4,3]])

interleave::a->[a]->[[a]]
interleave x []=[[x]]
interleave x (y:ys)=(x:y:ys):map (y:) (interleave x ys)
```

I used ghci interpreter and got the following answer:

```
[[2,3,4],[4,2,3],[3,4,2],[2,4,3],[3,2,4],[4,3,2]]
```

I run the following code :

```
map (interleave 2) [[3,4][4,3]]
```

and got the output :

```
[[[2,3,4],[4,2,3],[3,4,2]],[[2,4,3],[3,2,4],[4,3,2]]]
```

When I do dry run
I did the following:

```
concat( map (interleave 2) [[3,4][4,3]])
=>
concat( interleave 2 [3,4], interleave 2 [4,3])
=>
concat([[2,3,4],[4,2,3],[3,4,2]],[[2,4,3],[3,2,4],[4,3,2]])
=>
[2,3,4,4,2,3,3,4,2,2,4,3,3,4,2,4,3,2]
```

Can someone please explain how the expression evaluated?

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis are confusing. The `map (interleave 2) [[3,4], [4,3]]` will produce a list. Indeed:

```
   map (interleave 2) [[3,4][4,3]]
-> [interleave 2 [3, 4], interleave 2 [4, 3]]
```

now interleave will produce itself a list of lists where it inserts items at any possible insertion point, so:

```
   [interleave 2 [3, 4], interleave 2 [4, 3]]
-> [[[2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 4], [3, 4, 2]], [[2, 4, 3], [4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3]]]
```

This is thus a list of lists of lists of integers. Now we concatenate those, so that means that the two lists that are elements of the outer list are concatenated, so:

```
   concat [[[2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 4], [3, 4, 2]], [[2, 4, 3], [4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3]]]
-> [[2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 4], [3, 4, 2], [2, 4, 3], [4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.I forgot map will return a list.I just thought that it will apply the function on every element of list

Comment: In haskell, we cannot e.g. change contents of existing list, it has to be reflected in what is returned.